# WinSCP - How to Zip, Download and Delete a file?

Tags: download, zip, rm, winscp

How is it possible to Zip, Download and Delete (ZDD) a file in WinSCP?

For example, your local dir is Desktop and your remote dir (the one in your server machine) is, say, `/var/www/html` and you want to zip and download a particular dir or file, and then you want it to be removed the moment the download was finished.

---

[image]

---

### To further explain, in linux I could do, for example:

```
(
zip -r /var/www/html/dr.zip /var/www/html
scp /var/www/html/dr.zip USER@IP:/location
rm /var/www/html/dr.zip
)
```

I need similar thing for WinSCP yet I'm aware that the **WinSCP download mechanism** should be used and that it is different then the Nix `scp` utility.

### My question:

Do you know a way to achieve this with WinSCP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to ZIP files over any file transfer protocol (SFTP, FTP, SCP or WebDAV). That's why there's no such function in WinSCP, as it cannot be implemented reliably.

---

Though, if you have a shell access to the server, you can use a shell command to ZIP the files. That's actually, what the *Tar/GZip* [custom command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_command) does.

If you want it in one-go (zip-and-download), there's now a [WinSCP extension](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension) that does exactly this:
[Archive remote files to ZIP archive, download it, and optionally extract it](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension_archive_and_download).

Answer (score 2):

Under custom commands, there is now an option to "Archive and Download" a file or directory. You could use that command and delete the file after the download.

If you are going to do this often and really want to auto-delete after download, you could modify the Powershell script to delete the files after download. I will explain this for WinSCP version 5.17.6

Open this file in an editor: `c:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\Extensions\ArchiveDownload.WinSCPextension.ps1`

Line 151 should contain:

```
$session.GetFiles($source, $target, $True).Check()
```

Add these lines after the line I mentioned above:

```
$commands = "rm -rf $filesArgs"
$result = $session.ExecuteCommand($commands)
$result.Check()
```